# Import 4 data columns and drop one of them

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I would like to import 4 columns of data from a Dat-file(Fortran) and then drop the fourth one to use ListPlot3D and repeat this to drop the third one. When I used

```
temp1=Import["my path\bs1.dat","Table"];
```

and then

```
Drop[temp1, {}, {3}] >> temp2;
ListPlot3D[temp2]
```

the message was

> (Cannot open temp1 ), ("Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in
> Drop[$Failed,{},{3}]"), (temp2 must be a valid array or a list of
> valid arrays. >>)

Comment: I guess, if you have 4-column list, the simplest way to take 3 columns of them is `temp1[[All,{1,2,3}]]`

Comment: at the first, the Import command does not work?

Comment: @MohamedHajjaj What do you mean by "the Import command does not work"? The error message you provided is not related to `Import`. Note that "\" is an escape character. Use `FileNameJoin` not "my path\bs1.dat".

Comment: The message (can not open temp 1) means to me that Import command does not work

Comment: You want something like: `temp1 = Import["my path\\bs1.dat", "Table"]; temp2 = temp1[[All, ;;3]]; ListPlot3D[temp2]`. Note that you have to escape the backslash, using `\\` or use `FileNameJoin` as suggested. Alternatively, if you want to avoid temp2 and you know you will never need the fourth column from your data, then `temp1 = Import["my path\\bs1.dat", "Table"][[All, ;;3]]; ListPlot3D[temp1]`.

Comment: I want to thank all of you for your response. The problem has been solved with your help.

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
temp123 = temp1234[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];
```

solve the problem.